# Missing libraries debugging Django REST Framework app

Tags: python, django, debugging, visual-studio-code, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to debug my rest-framework django app using Visual Studio Code with no success at all. I followed the higly detailed guide in here https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-django but I'm getting errors with my libraries. My settings.INSTALLED_APPS is this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'django_filters',
]
```

My first error running in debug is this:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'corsheaders'`

Just to try, I commented out this library in my settings, and my next error was

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_filters'`

Ready to get at the end of the hole, I commented out that line too, and my new error is this:

`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?`

I'd need some hints to include my custom libraries and/or properly configure MySQL client.

Thanks in advance

Comment: the tutorial isn't providing any context of `django_filters` package

Comment: Would you know how to do that? Any hint is appreciated